# Last SDK to fully support Windows 98?

Tags: compiler-construction, sdk, windows-98

I need to do a quick port to windows 98. My code is raw C/C++, I just need the headers, the compiler, and preferably some documentation to clarify what is supported by Windows 98 API.

What is the latest SDK (with a compiler) that still fully supports Win98, with the win98 documentation?

Comment: This question is all the more amusing given your username. :-)

Comment: I never knew that SO questions could cause physical pain.

Comment: Maybe this is why he likes unix?

Comment: Microsoft-wise, the latest compiler to support Windows 98 was Visual Studio 2005 I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

1) Find yourself a compiler like OpenWatcom, DJGPP or Turbo C++

2)  Whatever your current platform (including Linux), create a Win98 VM to test your code on